# Office Word add-in – Msal using login redirect not working on Mac (Safari webkit 1.0)

Tags: safari, office-js, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c, office-dialog-api

We’re using Azure B2C to authenticate the users in the Word add-in. The library in Angular (14.1.2) that we use is MSAL which works as expected on Windows.

However, when using it on Mac, the redirect inside the add-in dialog gets stuck and doesn’t go to the Azure B2C page. It writes the cookies and local storage, but never redirects.

angular 14.1.2
azure/msal-angular 2.5.1
azure/msal-browser 2.32.1

**Call**
`this.msalService.loginRedirect().subscribe();`

**Msal Configuration**

```
`export function msalInstanceFactory(appConfigService: AppConfigService): IPublicClientApplication {
  const appConfig = appConfigService.config;
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: appConfig.aadB2CClientId,
      authority: 'https://${appConfig.aadB2CDomain}/${appConfig.aadB2CTenant}/${appConfig.aadB2CSIPolicy}',
      redirectUri: appConfig.aadB2CRedirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: getLocationOriginWithPath('logout'),
      knownAuthorities: [appConfig.aadB2CDomain],
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback: msalLoggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
        piiLoggingEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  });
}

export function msalGuardConfigFactory(appConfigService: AppConfigService): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: appConfigService.config.aadB2CConsentScopes,
      loginHint: getLoginHint(),
    },
  };
}`
```

The funny fact is that if I set a break point just before the execution of the loginRedirect and then press continue it works. So, I tried to set a timeout before that to see if it works but it doesn't.

Also tried to disable ITP security in Safari, but didn't take any effect.

Comment: Did you solve this? What did you do?

Comment: Please see this @JimbobTheSailor https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5898